# Three monitor setup not working on Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012

Using an ATI firepro 4800 card, with three monitors connected (1 dvi, 2 displayport) on Server 2008 R2 worked fine.

Ive now moved to a new machine, although identical spec, with a fresh Server 2012 install, and cannot get a three display output - only two.

When I try to extend the display on to the third monitor, I get the message "The display settings could not be saved. Please try a different combination of display settings"

The machine is a Dell Precision T1600.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like a driver problem.  I would contact ATI for assistance.

Comment: With reference to: http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx Your operating system is not listed. What drivers did you use?

Comment: Server2012 is not listed on the Dell support page either: http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/uk/en/ukbsdt1/Product/precision-t1600